# Detect changes of a select inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in Angularjs and i've some problems to detetect changes in my first select inside a ng-repeat. i want to detect changes to update the second select using a function in my controller.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="detailDemande in vm.demande.details track by $index">
    <td><select id="field_type" name="type" ng-model="detailDemande.type" ng-options="typeMateriel as typeMateriel.nom for typeMateriel in vm.types | orderBy:'nom' track by typeMateriel.id" >
                        </select></td>

<td><select  id="field_article" name="article" ng-model="detailDemande.article" ng-options="article as article.nom for article in vm.articles | orderBy:'nom' track by article.id">
                        <option value=""></option>
                    </select></td>
    </tr>
```

Please help 
Thanks

Comment: can you show an example of the data that you are populating these two dropdowns with, and how they relate to each other?

Comment: What is your *question*? All you posted is a vague requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is your first select (I've cut down the ng-options just for space):

```
<select id="field_type" name="type"
  ng-options="typeMateriel in vm.types"
  ng-model="vm.detailDemande.type" ng-change="vm.changeSelect()" />
```

Then this is your second select:

```
<select id="field_article" name="article"
  ng-options="article in vm.articles"
  ng-model="vm.detailDemande.article" />
```

In the first select's html there is the ng-change attribute, pointing at a method in the controller. You can use this to then change what appears in vm.articles:

```
changeSelect() {
  if (detailDemande.type === 'foo') {
    this.articles = ['new', 'list'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. But when i do like that all second select take same value :(. I want, for exemple,  when i change the value of the select in the second line it update only select in the same line not all other select inside  the table. Any idea plz?